# How to use palette window decorators in Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, decorator, palette

is there an open solution to use palette window decorators in Java/Swing like in the following screenshot? [JNIWrapper](https://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper) can do this but it is neither open nor free.

[image: Small window decorator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the slolution:

```
User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(new HWND(Native.getWindowPointer(frame)), -20, new Pointer(0x00000080L));
```

User32 is part of the JNA platform.jar. But most probably it only runs with a 32bit JVM. With 64bit you have to call SetWindowLongPtr but this doesn't seem to be mapped in JNA (UnsatisfiedLinkError).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [JNA library](https://github.com/twall/jna/)? Should be enough if you just have to call Windows API.